# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl ProcessException

Tags: android, aidl

I am not able to build Aidl Library.
Error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 
>  'D:\mysdk\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aidl.exe' with arguments 
> {-pD:\mysdk\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\framework.aidl -...
>       
> dC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl6013369886374174489.d ...\dev\myaidllibrary\ICoffeeMakerRemoteService.aidl}

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2-rc1'
    // needed for Android Studio
    apt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2-rc1'
    apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.0'
}
```

Directory Structure:

> aidl->
>   ICoffeeMakerRemoteService.aidl
>   Ingredient.aidl
>   java->
>   Ingredient.java

I'm stuck with these, tried possible solutions.

Comment: @siva35 tried. It is not working. Thnks

Comment: Refer https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-parcel/pull/92

Answer (score 4):

I got the same mistake, but I fixed it.
I guess you want to "Passing Objects over IPC", so do I.

My problem is that I missed the package define in the object aidl such as Rect.aidl, so please try to add package into your aidl file.

for example:

> Rect.aidl

```
package android.graphics;  // important

// Declare Rect so AIDL can find it and knows that it implements
// the parcelable protocol.
parcelable Rect;
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, this happen when I define overload methods with different signatures in aidl. Seem like overload methods is not supported.

Not allowed:

```
public void methodA(int a);
public void methodA(int a, String b);
```

Allowed:

```
public void methodA(int a);
public void methodB(int a, String b);
```

Found more is not allowed, cannot define String array in the signature
Not Allowed:

```
public void methodA(String[] a);
```

Answer (score 1):

I **rename** the **aidl's** *package* on **Left navigation bar** , and 
Consistent with the code in ***.aidl。

Answer (score 0):

Try to build with --debug option and looking for "can be an out type, so you must declare it as in, out or inout."

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same kind of error.
The reason was the .aidl file I was copying to client application which access the service was not under the proper package.
Just try to create the package and make sure you copy the aidl file under proper package name of the app.

Answer (score -1):

change build tool to

```
buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"
```

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick/issues/46

```
1.Delete android/app/build Folder
2.build -> clean
3.build -> rebuild
try again.
```